# multiple select angular-materialize

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular-materialize to generate a multiple select : 
http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/ 
I'm using ng-model to retrieve the selected items, all this works, however I tried to add a search box in order to filter what I need.

my problem is I search for the first time and check the value, but then when I make an other search (that doesn't lead to the previously selected item) it is deleted and I'm only left with the last selected items. 
So my questions are :

1/ is there a way to conserve all the selected items even with multiple search? 
2/ is it possible to always have the dropdown "active" meaning I won't have to click in order to have the list ? (if that helps the previous problem)

Thank you